# Decrypting AES cipher text using CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to follow the instructions seen in the image to complete mutual authentication between a bluetooth smartcard reader and a mobile application.

Based on how I've interpreted the instructions, here is my attempt:

```
const randomNumbers = 'd3be845b701b37eff9f24ea6108c0f99';
const masterKey = '41435231323535552d4a312041757468';

const d1 = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
  {
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(randomNumbers),
  },
  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(masterKey),
  {
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('00000000000000000000000000000000'),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
  },
),

const combined = randomNumbers.concat(d1.toString());

const d2 = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
  {
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(combined),
  },
  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(masterKey),
  {
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('00000000000000000000000000000000'),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
  },
);
```

When I put this together into a full escape command and send it to the reader, I do get a response confirming that the format is valid. The problem is that the response doesn't contain a session key, which means that my encryption didn't work and I can't unlock full reader functionality.

Based on the decryption instructions below, is it possible I've misinterpreted this process?

[image]

Comment: I can't find a bug in the code. It can also be easily checked, e.g. with http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/. What is irritating is that the CBC-mode is specified, but nothing is said about the IV. A wrong IV can be the reason for the issue. Also the described process is a bit odd: decrypting, concatenating and then decrypting again. In the last step I would rather expect encryption (however, this is described twice, so it will probably be correct). But these are all just speculations. In my opinion, the problem is mainly a poor specification.

Comment: [This](https://flomio.com/forums/topic/rewriting-customer-master-key-acr1255u-j1/) could be pretty interesting. Although it doesn't solve the problem, it shows how others interpret the description and what they have done. Maybe it makes sense to contact support.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks again for the detailed response. That forum post you linked I've been looking at for the past 3-4 hours! The resolution seemed to mention they used ECB instead of CBC? I've tried removing the IV and using ECB but the resulting decrypted string is exactly the same so assume it's a red herring. I think you're right about the process being odd, and about expecting encryption in the last step, that's what seems logical. Unfortunately the manufacturer is based in Hong Kong and no response as of yet due to the unrest.

Comment: @Topaco I think the answer lies in ignoring some of the documentation and making some assumptions. I don't know enough about enc/decryption processes, but I do think that it would make more sense sending an encrypted string back to the reader to decrypt itself. Do you think it's worth attempting that?

Comment: CBC and ECB provide different results. In your case, the results differ _only_ in the second block (1 block = 16 bytes) because a 0-IV is used (if an arbitrary IV is used, the result would also differ in the first block). Thus, it certainly makes sense to test the ECB-mode. Probably it would also be worthwhile to try an encryption instead of a decryption as the last step (in the forum this was probably done this way: _...Then I have to send an **encrypted** version of [those random numbers + new master key]..._. The problem (according to the forum) may be that the unit has to be reset first.

Comment: @Topaco I've decompiled an app that does this too - it's definitely AES/CBC/NoPadding! Can just about understand the code so will update later, should be enough to determine the solution

Comment: OK. Concerning your (meanwhile deleted) comment: `encrypt` returns a `CipherParams`-object that encapsulates multiple data, including the ciphertext, [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output), which is contained in `CipherParams#ciphertext` as `WordArray`. Thus, `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(...)` returns the ciphertext as hex-string. This page http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/ is well suited for verification as it allows hexadecimal input for text, key and IV and supports both ECB and CBC.

Comment: Sorry deleted it as not to confuse further but appreciate the explanation. I'll make use of that page for verifying - thanks! Will update once I've got my head around the decompiled code. [Fun!](https://imgur.com/Js6exWu)